# SIM card cannot be detected, cannot open "SIM Card Manager"

Tags: settings, sim-card

The SIM Card Manager on the Settings cannot be opened. The SIM, contacts, and messages also cannot be detected on my cp. Even the mobile data can't connect. It says "Insert SIM card", but the SIM card is already inserted.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- The SIM card is defective
- The SIM is inserted the wrong way
- The tiny metallic connectors of the SIM card plug are deformed (this is my personal experience)

Answer (score 0):

I had had a case when inserting a newer SIM into an older phone:
It seems the voltages were not compatible, and the older phone did not detect the SIM.
(Unfortunately the contract of the last SIM that had worked had expired in the meantime)